# WPF - TextBox not binding properly when set to readonly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox

I have TextBox that I'm using to add (only to add and not read) file path into DB. Text property is set when user selects certain file (OpenFileDialog). So, I set it in readonly state and it won't bind properly. When I remove readonly it works fine.

```
<Button Name="btnAddFile" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="23" Height="23" Click="AddFilePath"/>
<TextBox Name="tbxFilePath" Height="23" Text="{Binding FilePath}" Width="364" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

When I use:

```
Text="{Binding FilePath, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

it sometimes work but most of the time it doesn't (?!). I could use TextBlock or Label but I would really like to understand what is going on and use TextBox.

I'm using Entity Framework but don't think it does matter.

Question: How can I programmatically add text to TextBox control which is readonly and be able to bind it.

EDIT: I figured out what the problem is. When I set focus on TextBox **after** I set it's Text property from code-behind, it works. I guess it has to notify that Text is changed when I do it from code-behind. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `OneWay` Binding?

MSDN reads:

> **OneWay** Updates the binding target (target) property when the binding source (source) changes. This type of binding is appropriate if the control being bound is implicitly *read-only*.

Which I think covers your scenario.

The *target* is your TextBox `Text` property and your *source* is your `FilePath` property on your ViewModel.

Use:

```
Text="{Binding FilePath, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

#### EDIT

This answer assumes you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your ViewModel.

#### EDIT

The correct binding mode is `OneWayToSource`. Confirmed by OP.

Comment: I'm still getting confused about source-target sometimes. I've tried OneWay and it doesn't work. As I said, if I set focus on TextBox after Text property is changed it all fine even without setting Mode to anything. I guess that I need to notify that Text property is changed (which automatically happens when I set focus to control) but I don't know how.

Comment: That's what `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is for.

Comment: Only workaround is to place tbxFilePath.Focus() is code behind.

Comment: Implemented  INotifyPropertyChanged and it works great but you were wrong about Mode. It should be Mode=OneWayToSource cause I'm updating my source and data flow is from target to source. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ivan you are totally right, it should be `OneWayToSource`. I'm glad you got it working. I too get confuse about the whole source - target direction sometimes. I'll edit my answer.